# Proof involving the sequential definition of a limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm having trouble with how to prove this:

Consider the function $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and let $k \in \mathbb{R}$. Assume that every sequence $\{x_n\} \subset (-\infty,k)$ that converges to $k$ is such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} g(x_n)=L$, and every sequence $\{y_n\} \subset (k,\infty)$ that converges to $k$ is such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} g(y_n)=L$. Prove $\lim_{x \to k} g(x)=L$.

I know the proof needs the sequential definition of a limit, but I don't know where to go from there.

Answer (score 1):

For any sequence $(x_n)$ in $\mathbb R -\{k\}$ that converges to $k$, we can separate it into two subsequences, one in $(-\infty, k)$ and the other in $(k, \infty)$. The two subsequences must both converge to $k$. It follows that $(g(x_n))$ must be a sequence converging to $L$.

Answer (score 0):

According to definition of limit,
We have to show,
for given $\epsilon>0$ ,there exists a $\delta>0$ s•t $|g(x)-L|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-k|<\delta$

From our given sequential criteria,
For a sequence,$x_n=k+\frac{1}{n}$
$\lim_{n\to\infty}$$g(x_n)=L$
Now, for any $\delta$ there is a natural no $m$ such that $\frac{1}{m}<\delta$
So, $x_n$  inside of $ (k,k+\delta)$ for all n≥m
hence
$|g(x)-L|<\epsilon$

Similarly consider a sequence
$y_n=k-\frac{1}{n}$ to show left hand limit also exists from given sequential criteria .